# GitLab CI: prevent duplicate job executions after merge

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My project uses the git flow approach for our JavaScript frontend. On the feature branch we execute unit tests, Eslint and build before on commit. Before merging to dev all CI jobs of the feature branch need to succeed.

After merging to DEV the same jobs are executed again before deploying to the test environment. Can I prevent these steps from executing again after merge? Or is this best practice to ensure that nothing broke while merging? (It seems like waist of pipeline minutes and development time.)

Comment: Why would re-running tests be time lost? When merging you'll potentially (probably even) have changes on `dev` and the repo state will be different than in the merged branch, that's why you should run tests on `dev` after merge. If this feels like time lost, maybe you can have a shorter pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a best practice to run CI after merge.

Anyway, you can disable it using **except** keyword

```
job:
  script:
   - ./build
  except:
    - dev
```

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Comment: However I want to ensure that everything is fine before merging.

Comment: @SimonThiel You can  enable "Fast-forward merge" or "Merge commit with semi-linear history" in Project Settings->General-Merge Request, thus only fast-forward will  be possible.